# How to Force Bootstrap Navbar Fix To Top Push Down(slide) Elements Under

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

As you can see at [This Demo](http://www.bootply.com/cqIXThTvrL) Bootstrap 3 Navbar Fixed to Top is not behaving like regular navbras on sliding down elements which are after the navbar in small screens. Instead it is overlaying the navbar on top of content elements. Now can you please let me know if there is a way to force fix navbar also acts like regular navbars on pushing the content down and up on sliding?

Thanks

Comment: The fixed version isn't really intended to work that way. By making it fixed it's sort of "hovered" over the main body content, and as such the collapsed nav will hover over the body content when expanded. Trying to get it to work otherwise will most likely involve some custom JS/JQ to accomplish, but that goes against the idea of the fixed navbar. I'd suggest simply using the static version if you need it to push the content down when the nav is expanded on smaller screens.

Comment: Also, if you stick with the fixed version, you need to add `padding-top: 70px;` to the CSS styling of the body element.

Comment: Agree @MattD i wasn't thinking on the fact that the idea is to have a fixed navbar and push the content also, the only way is to use a Jquery height calculation.

Comment: @PatrickLC I went ahead and wrote up a solution that'll work, but also explained why it's honestly not a very good idea to implement such a feature to begin with, mainly becuase it's completely pointless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, so you can kind of get it to do what you want, but allow me to show you why doing this is honestly a bad idea because **in the end it's just pointless.**

The following answer will use the snippet bellow for refference. You may need to view it full screen which means you may also need to adjust he width of your browser window to get the collapsed nav to show up.

```js
$(function() {
  $('button.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
    var value = $('body').css('padding-top');
    if (value === '70px') {
      $('body').css('padding-top', '+=235');
    } else {
      $('body').css('padding-top', '70');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

The bit of jQuery at the top is what you can use to adjust the 'padding-top' value of your body element.

Initially, per the [official Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top) regarding fixed navbars, you have to add a `padding-top` of 70px to your page's body tag, so the navbar doesn't overlap the page content. As such, to get the page content to move down when you're at the top of the page you have to adjust this padding to fit based on your nav.

But this is where things start to get a little pointless.

When you're at the very top of your page content, it gets pushed down and looks kind of okay, similar to the normal Bootstrap navbar:

[image]

However, scroll down about halfway so your body content is now under your navbar and expand the nav again. You get this slight little jump with the content which really **doesn't do anything useful for the user.**

The fixed navbar is for when you want your nav to always be visible no matter where you are in scrolling your page, which means on mobile sites it has to hover over the content of your page when expanded. **Given this, having the body content of your page pushed down when you expand a fixed Bootstrap navbar in mobile view is really quite pointless.**

I've provided an answer in case you or anyone else really needs some kind of solution, maybe due to a manager or client that insists on having this type of functionality, but I simply wanted to point out how pointless it really is, that way you might explain it to them as well, possibly at your own risk. :P

Comment: Thanks for the solution as well as the explanation.

Comment: Why is it pointless to push the content down? Wouldn't the user need to know somehow that they must tap the menubar again to display all content? I have seen so many sites that push content, I thought it was the standard.

Comment: @rontornambe They're asking for a *fixed* navbar, which means they're intending for the content to go under the navbar as the user scrolls down the page. When using Bootstrap's fixed navbar, it normally just covers content on the page until the user collapses it again. Wanting content pushed down actually goes against this convention, and when halfway down a page introduces a a visual annoyance as the content makes a slight, pointless jump. Scroll the content in my example to see what I'm talking about, and compare it to the default functionality of both a fixed and non-fixed Bootstrap navbar.

Comment: Thanks for explanation @MattD. I did find a way of pushing content down without a bump, but I still think it is confusing to users.

Answer (score 0):

The key to pushing down content on mobile devices was to add the "navbar-static-top" to .navbar:

```
if(screen.width >= 768) {
    $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    $('body').css("padding-top", 128);
} else {
    $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top navbar-fixed').addClass("navbar-static-top");
    $('body').css({"padding-top": 0, "margin-top": 144});
}
```